# Replace List of ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a custom ArrayAdapter that uses an `ArrayList<OrderedProductItem>` for my ListView. Inside this ListView I have an AutoCompleteTextView that also uses a custom ArrayAdapter with an `ArrayList<Product>`. On initialization this AutoCompleteTextView contains the Names of all Products (around 1250), minus 1 (the OrderedProductItem's Product).

The User can then use a Spinner to select a Product-Tag and I create a filtered `ArrayList<Product>`, so I only get a list of all Products containing this Product-Tag (still minus the 1). So, my question is: **What is the best way to replace an ArrayAdapter's object-list?**

I know I can just re-create and re-assign a new ArrayAdapter instance in my ListActivity:

```
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.item_view, myList);
setListAdapter(myAdapter);
```

I also know I can use a clear and then an addAll to replace everything:

```
// NOTE: myAdapter.setNotifyOnChange is kept on default (true)
myAdapter.clear();
myAdapter.addAll(myList);
```

I guess the second one is probably best, since we don't want to create a new Instance every time, or does ArrayAdapter have some kind of method like `setArray()` and I just missed it when looking for it? Or is there even another way that is better for performance than this second option?

Comment: why are you scared of the performance?

Comment: @blackbelt Well, first of it's Mobile, so performance should always be a concern. Also, each of my ListView-items contains around 10 View-elements each (Spinner, ImageView, AutoCompleteTextView, etc.) All in all I already managed to make the performance a lot better by using sorted Lists and re-using instances, and right now I want to keep it this way. Also, I mainly made this question since I couldn't find a `setArray()` and the second part was a for-loop adding them one by one, but while making the question I found the `addAll()`  (which still uses a loop behind the scenes I can imagine.)

Comment: performance are a concern if you have performance issues. Back to the main question, the heavier operation is   `getView`, that has to inflate/measure/layout/draw the ListView's children, and in both of case you are scheduling *it*. In my opinion it does make any difference

Comment: Actually, it does make a difference. Creating and setting a new adapter will clear and reset the list and recycler - the views that could have been reused are released and have to be recreated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you want to change data of customAdapter make a public method in adapter

```
public void updateData(ArrayList<T> list){
 mAdapterProductList=list;
}
```

and now whenever u want to update data use these codes:

```
adpter.updateData(mUpdatedList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanges();
```

No need to re-instantiate your adapter

Comment: You can also call notifyDataSetChanges() inside adapter updateData(ArrayList<T> list) method.

Comment: This worked for me but I also had to override the getCount() method to return the sizeof my list.

Comment: Is `mAdapterProductList = list;` the same as `mAdapterProductList.clear();` + `mAdapterProductList.addAll(list);` ?

Comment: @rohan-taneja.
Yup, it will work the same. just add notifyDataSetChanges() in next line

Comment: @PradeepYaduvansy can you please look into this? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56454443/clear-addall-vs-re-initialise-list-recyclerviewadapter-android?noredirect=1#comment99502533_56454443

Answer (score 0):

Create callback interface and use it

```
public MyAdapter extends ... {

    public interface GetActualListCallback {
        List<OrderedProductItem> getList();
    }

    private GetActualListCallback mCallback;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resId, GetActualListCallback callback) {
        super(context, resId)
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mCallback.getList().size();
    }

        ....

}
```

In your activity implement this interface.

```
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.item_view, this);
setListAdapter(myAdapter);
```

After update list just call notifyDataSetChanged() on myAdapter