# clear + addAll vs re-initialise list RecyclerViewAdapter android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, custom-adapter

What's the different between 1 and 2:

1.

```
public void updatePostList(ArrayList<Post> updatedPosts) {
   this.postList.clear();
   this.postList.addAll(updatedPosts);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

2.

```
public void updatePostList(ArrayList<Post> updatedPosts) {
   this.postList = updatedPosts;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

For me, #1 doesn't work as calling `this.postList.clear()` clears `updatedPosts` too instead of just clearing `postList` and I can't understand why.

Comment: May be they both refer to same array list, will need to see where both array lists originates

Comment: The `updatePostList` method is inside the `CustomRecyclerViewAdapter`. The `updatedPosts` list is sent to this method from the `Activity`.

Comment: The first point represents reusing the same `list` object. The Second point represents dereferencing and referencing the `list` from `Activity`

Comment: Yes but the question is why does calling `this.postList.clear()` clear `updatedPosts` too instead of just clearing `postList`.

Comment: I think post list is the array list passed to constructor of adapter from activity, may be you are calling updatePostList with the same array list from activity, csn u pls share your activity code?